# AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'build' -- Grid search CV, I have done all changes suggested from similar posts

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gridsearchcv

I am fully aware that this question has been asked before but i have tried all of the ways to make it work as my version of tensorflow is == 2.11 and i also imported keras in this method as suggested from previous posts :

```
**from tensorflow import keras**

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
import scikeras
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier

model = KerasClassifier(model=Identifiying_the_numbers, optimizer = Adam())

batch_size = [10, 40]
epochs = [10, 50]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False))
grid_result = grid.fit(train_x, train_y, verbose = 0)
```

Here is the network incase it helps

```
#Creating a network
Identifiying_the_numbers = Sequential(name='Identfying_hand_written_digits')
Identifiying_the_numbers.add(Input(shape=(28,28,1)))
Identifiying_the_numbers.add(Conv2D(4,6,activation = 'relu'))
Identifiying_the_numbers.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
Identifiying_the_numbers.add(Conv2D(5,4,activation = 'relu'))
Identifiying_the_numbers.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
#Identifiying_the_numbers.add(Conv2D(2,4,activation = 'relu'))
Identifiying_the_numbers.add(Flatten())
Identifiying_the_numbers.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
        
Identifiying_the_numbers.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate= 0.001),loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[tensorflow.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
    tensorflow.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

So even though i have tried many ways of getting rid of this error i am still getting it any help would be appreciated

Here is the error i got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 12
     10 param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
     11 grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False))
---> 12 grid_result = grid.fit(train_x, train_y, verbose = 0)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:789, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    786 cv_orig = check_cv(self.cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
    787 n_splits = cv_orig.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)
--> 789 base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
    791 parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, pre_dispatch=self.pre_dispatch)
    793 fit_and_score_kwargs = dict(
    794     scorer=scorers,
    795     fit_params=fit_params,
   (...)
    801     verbose=self.verbose,
    802 )

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:89, in clone(estimator, safe)
     87 new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     88 for name, param in new_object_params.items():
---> 89     new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
     90 new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
     91 params_set = new_object.get_params(deep=False)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:70, in clone(estimator, safe)
     68 elif not hasattr(estimator, "get_params") or isinstance(estimator, type):
     69     if not safe:
---> 70         return copy.deepcopy(estimator)
     71     else:
     72         if isinstance(estimator, type):

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\copy.py:153, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    151 copier = getattr(x, "__deepcopy__", None)
    152 if copier is not None:
--> 153     y = copier(memo)
    154 else:
    155     reductor = dispatch_table.get(cls)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scikeras\_saving_utils.py:83, in deepcopy_model(model, memo)
     81 def deepcopy_model(model: keras.Model, memo: Dict[Hashable, Any]) -> keras.Model:
     82     _, (model_bytes,) = pack_keras_model(model)
---> 83     new_model = unpack_keras_model(model_bytes)
     84     memo[model] = new_model
     85     return new_model

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scikeras\_saving_utils.py:53, in unpack_keras_model(packed_keras_model)
     51 model: keras.Model = load_model(temp_dir)
     52 model.load_weights(temp_dir)
---> 53 model.optimizer.build(model.trainable_variables)
     54 return model

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:975, in OptimizerV2.__getattribute__(self, name)
    973 if name in self._hyper:
    974     return self._get_hyper(name)
--> 975 raise e

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:965, in OptimizerV2.__getattribute__(self, name)
    963 """Overridden to support hyperparameter access."""
    964 try:
--> 965     return super().__getattribute__(name)
    966 except AttributeError as e:
    967     # Needed to avoid infinite recursion with __setattr__.
    968     if name == "_hyper":

AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'build'
```